# How can I make the value of a variable equal to another but delay the setting?

Tags: angularjs

My application has a $rootScope variable that is set to a non-zero value when there is an Ajax 
request in progress. I set a spinning wheel to show when this variable has a value of more 
than zero. Pseudo code:

```
$rootScope.pendingRequests > 0 then show the spinning wheel
```

The result is that for very fast requests the wheel flashes briefly. I would like to avoid this flash by having the wheel appear only if the requests have been in progress for more than 500ms. My idea is to have another variable called $rootScope.pendingRequestsDebounced and have this follow the value of $rootScope.pendingRequests like this:

- If $rootScope.pendingRequests has a value of more than 0 for at **least 500 millisecond**s then set: $rootScope.pendingRequestsDebounced = $rootScope.pendingRequests
- If $rootScope.pendingRequests equals 0 then immediately set: $rootScope.pendingRequestsDebounced = $rootScope.pendingRequests (with no delay).

Comment: Is your ajax call is sync call or async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $timeout service to kick in 500 ms later to check for the pending requests:

```
if ($rootScope.pendingRequests == 0)
{
     $rootScope.pendingRequestsDebounced = $rootScope.pendingRequests;
}
else
{
     var currentTimeoutHandler = $timeout(function()
     {
        $rootScope.pendingRequestsDebounced = $rootScope.pendingRequests;
        //You can keep checking 500 ms later by creating new timeout call right in here
     },500);
}
```

EDIT:  The function passed to $timeout executes only one time, and in this case 500ms later. if you want to execute that function only one time (which it seems you are) then the code above should suffice. However, if you want to call a function every 500ms you need to write:

```
var currentTimeoutHandler = $timeout(checkFn, 500);  
function checkFn() 
{ 
    $rootScope.pendingRequestsDebounced = $rootScope.pendingRequests; 
    currentTimeoutHandler = $timeout(checkFn, 500);  //Re-execute this function after 500ms
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with your comment and show how I could check again?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this

```
var timeoutTask = null;

$scope.showLoader = false;
$rootScope.$watch('pendingRequests', function(val, oldVal) {
    $timeout.cancel(timeoutTask);
    if (val) {
        timeoutTask = $timeout(function() {
            $scope.showLoader = true;
        },500);
    }
});
```

markup

```
<div id="loader" ng-show="showLoader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer and set it to 500ms and whenever it goes to (or below) zero, reset it back to 500ms and check the spin value.

Use $watch to monitor the value. Once it becomes zero, kill the timer from above and proceed.